# Add character at a position to a string with notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

How do I insert a character into a string at a given position in Notepad++?

For example

00000000 to 000000-00

Comment: Why are the before and after digits different? Is your issue only about formatting or does it involve a calculation? If it *does* involve calculations, can you provide the formula(s) that have to be aplied? Thanks.

Comment: Your before and after examples don't make sense. What is the logic behind replacing `12345678` with `12825-636` etc?

Comment: I've made quite a big change to the question, hopefully it's clearer and will also be useful for others

Comment: @Dave Now we have an answer that **doesn't match your modified question**, which has 5 digits before `-` **not** 6. I've no idea which is correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this to the Find What (in the Replace box). Change the number (6) to the acquired number of characters!

```
^(.{6})
```

And replace with

```
$1-
```

to insert the dash. You could do `$1a` to insert the character `a`

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: Heyyy guyyy, Thais so muchh. Minutes before i got with this: ([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) to \1- but thanks so muchhhh!! Really

Comment: @Emanuel Now you have an answer that **doesn't match the  question, which has 5 digits before `-` **not** 6. Which is correct?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes David, the correct is the answer of Dave. In my case i've used  ([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) xD

Comment: Easy guys. @Dave is clearly a bot. *upvote*